# Can a spouse get an Indian visa & OCI for a US-born child from an EU country, if the husband is in India?

Tags: india, visa

I have heard both parents need to be present in same country for applying minor's Indian visa, with only exception of death or divorce.

Note that - Father is not in the same country as Mother. Parents of child are married.

I have the same question for obtaining OCI, if father is in different country.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about bureaucratic procedure, not the law or legal process.

Comment: @Nij please advise where to ask this question, it is really important for me.

Comment: I don't know where you should go, just that here isn't it.

Comment: Where have you heard that both parents need to be in the same country? Most if not all of the application process is online bar the need to have certain documents notarized by a notary public. The main issue is finding a notary who'd be able to assist with this process and the rules around notarization depend on the region.